# Pulling a load over a smooth peg

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

Edit: I am struggling with how to start with a question, I would be thankful if I can receive some guidance it would be great.

> A load of 100N hanging vertically is hauled at constant speed over a smooth peg using a light rope. If the angle between the two parts of the rope is 50 Degrees, find the resultant force on the peg.

Note: I am aware that this question has been answered in [Yahoo asks](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120216152030AAf27t4), however, it is not what I am after. I am struggling on how to visualize and understand the problem so I can work it out myself.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: Originally, I was struggling with how to visualize the problem, and understand what the question was asked using the information provided. I turned to yahoo asks, hoping someone can explain the way they think about the concept, but all I can find is the solution to the worked problem. I wanted to work the question out myself, so I was simply seeking guidance and illustration for how to start the problems. Farcher was being helpful and provided an explanation of the concept of the given problem. Regardless, I apologize for not reading the policy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the peg is in equilibrium the net force on it is zero.
In this problem there are 3 forces on the peg which are the two tension forces of $100\,\rm N$ due to the rope and a force $F$ due to the support for the peg as shown in the left-hand diagram.

[image]

As the resultant of these three forces is zero their vector addition (shown in the left hand diagram) form a closed triangle.

The sum of the two tension forces (the resultant force on the peg) must be equal in magnitude of the force $F$ and opposite in direction to $F$.
So using trigonometry you can find the magnitude of $F$ and hence the required resultant force on the peg.

Comment: Thank you very much Farcher. That is much much clearer and easier to understand.